# No se cargan valores de select anidados en modal de editar

Tags: javascript, select, modal

Tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo,tengo una tabla donde se muestran los item registrados al final de cada columna tengo un boton de `editar`, al dar `click` en cualquiera, abrira un `modal` con los datos cargados, anteriormente `registrados`,todos los datos cargan perfectamente en su input, excepto dos `select` anidados.

si intento hacer un update en cualquiero otro campo, primero debo de volver a elegir la Category para que me aparezca su Item, de otra manera no hara nada y no actualiza.

Solo me falta que cargar ese valor cuando se abra el modal de editar, pero no se como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion que se ejecuta al dar click en el boton editar, y donde cargo los valores en los input.

```js
function editModal(cat_name,idSub,numFile,description_item,price_item,manufacturer,model_item,reorder_Level,target_Stock,image,
    commentt,registerDate,id_category,id_supplier,id_unit,id_location,id_engineer,name_sub)
    {
    
     if(parseInt(status) === 0)
     {
      swal({
      title: "Para actualizar debe cambiar status del Item\n"+ description_item,
      text: "¡Imposible actualizar!",
      icon: "warning",
     });
     } else{
      // $('#modalParaEditar').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
      document.getElementById("id").value = cat_name+ "-" +"00"+ idSub+"-"+numFile;
      document.getElementById("EdititemDes").value = description_item;
      document.getElementById("Editprice").value = price_item;
      document.getElementById("Editmanufacturer").value = manufacturer;
      document.getElementById("Editmodel").value = model_item;
      document.getElementById("Editmin").value = reorder_Level;
      document.getElementById("Editmax").value = target_Stock;
      document.getElementById('imagenEditar').src = "http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/" + image;
      document.getElementById("Editcomment").value = commentt;
      document.getElementById("lastDate").value = registerDate;
      document.getElementById("Editcategory").value = id_category; //
      document.getElementById("Editsupplier").value = id_supplier; //
      document.getElementById("Editunit").value = id_unit; //
      document.getElementById("Edititem").value = idSub; 
      document.getElementById("Editlocation").value = id_location; //
      document.getElementById("Editengineer").value = id_engineer; //
      document.getElementById("pk").value = numFile;
      $("#modalParaEditar").modal();
     }
    }
```

Aqui estoy cargando los valores de los `select`, sin embargo el select `Item` aparece en blanco.

Ejemplo: Si quiero modificar el valor de cualquier otro `input` pero dejar la misma `Category`, debo seleccionarlo antes para que me aparezca su `Item` y asi poder hacer exitosamente el update, de otra manera no lo hara.

```
document.getElementById("Editcategory").value = id_category; 
document.getElementById("Edititem").value = idSub;
```

Esta es la `function` que se ejecuta al selecccionar el `select` de `Category` y muestre los datos del siguiente.

```js
function secondCombo(id_category)
{
console.log("Entre a second combo");
console.log(id_category);
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('GET', 'http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/sub_category.php?id_category='+ id_category);
  x.send();
  x.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (x.status == 200 && x.readyState == 4) {
   //Toma los dos selectores
      var combo = document.getElementById('item');
   var comboEditar = document.getElementById('Edititem');
     var JSONdata = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
     var sub =JSONdata.subItems;
   console.log(JSONdata);
   document.getElementById('item').options.length = 0;
   document.getElementById('Edititem').options.length = 0;
   //Llena el combo para editar
   for(var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++)
   {
    //Crea una opcion de selector
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    //Aniade propiedades a la opcion
    option.value = sub[i].id_category;
   // option.innerHTML = sub[i].idSub;
    option.innerHTML = sub[i].n;
    comboEditar.appendChild(option);
   }

   //Llena el combo para agregar
   for(var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++)
   {
    //Crea una opcion de selector
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    //Aniade propiedades a la opcion
    option.value = sub[i].id_category;
   // option.innerHTML = sub[i].idSub;
    option.innerHTML = sub[i].n;
    combo.appendChild(option);
   }
    }
  }
}
```

En conclusion, necesito que al querer editar y se abra el respectivo `modal`, Item tambien muestre su valor con el que fue registrado, ya que de otra manera no se puede hacer el `update`.

Este es el codigo `html` donde se manda a llamar la funcion para que asigne el item a la `category`, elegida, solo que para editarlo el item no muestra su valor, es decir si quiero dejar la misma `category` debo de elegir para que me aparezca el valor y luego, solo luego si actualiza.

```
   <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                      <label>Category</label>
                      <select onchange="secondCombo(this.value)"  class="form-control" id="Editcategory" >
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

El boton lo estoy creando dentro de una funcion js para crear y llenar la tabla, y solo mando a llama la function `editmodal` para que asigne los valores a los input.

```
edit.setAttribute("onclick", "editModal('" + articulos[i].cat_name +"', '" +
    articulos[i].idSub +"','" +
    articulos[i].numFile +"', '" + articulos[i].description_item +"', '" +
    articulos[i].price_item +"', '" + articulos[i].manufacturer +"', '"+
    articulos[i].model_item +"', '" +   articulos[i].reorder_Level +"','" +
    articulos[i].target_Stock +"','" + articulos[i].image +"','" +
    articulos[i].commentt +"','" + articulos[i].registerDate +"', '"+
    articulos[i].id_category +"','" + articulos[i].id_supplier +"','" +
    articulos[i].id_unit +"','" + articulos[i].id_location +"','" + articulos[i].id_engineer +"','" + articulos[i].idSub +"',)");
```

Comment: Podrías incluir el html de tu modal? y el html donde se encuentra el boton editar? y la funcion secondcombo cuando la mandas llamar?

Comment: He editado mi publicacion @Ricardo , gracias por contestar.

Comment: Cuando tu seleccionas un Category el combo de item funciona correctamente pero al editar no entra  la funcion secondcombo y por lo tanto no carga el combo de item, y este se queda en blanco?

Comment: la funcion secondCombo entra correctamente si este quiere actualizar esa parte, pero si quiere actualizar cualquier otro campo dejando el item con su respectiva category, al abrir el modal la parte de item no muestra su valor, y se debe de elegir la misma category para que aparezca su item, de otra manera no actualiza.

Comment: Lo que alcanzo a entenderte, es que el item te lo deja en blanco porque la funcion secondCombo nunca entra al editar por que el evento onChange nunca ocurre, por eso es que necesitas seleccionar la category de nuevo para que el evento onChange ocurra y así se ejecute la funcion.

Comment: Exactamente, pero ¿Que necesito hacer para que me cargue el valor del item cuando se abra el modal editar, pero ejecutando el seconCombo si se quiere actualizar esa parte?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86153/discussion-between-virusdetected-and-ricardo).

Comment: Tengo un problema similar, logro editar los valores en el primer Item pero al abrir el segundo o cualquier otro los select salen en blanco.

Comment: Yo estaba usando apis, hice uno para traer los datos del segundo select dependiendo del primero, y en js solo hice una function, llamando dicha api, ademas de que en html, puse el onchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que alcanzo a entenderte, es que el item te lo deja en blanco porque la función `secondCombo` nunca entra al editar por que el evento `onChange` nunca ocurre, por eso es que necesitas seleccionar la category de nuevo para que el evento `onChange` ocurra y así se ejecute la `funcion`.

Podrías mandar llamar la funcion `secondCombo` en el js de tu modal y mandarle como parámetro el `value` de `Editcategory`.

Así cada vez que el modal se abra, tomara ese valor y ejecutará la función:

```
var select = document.getElementById("Editcategory")
var value = select.value //El valor seleccionado
secondCombo(value);
```

Creo que esta parte es fácil, solo es un ejemplo, ya podrías aplicarlo como mejor te convenga.

Espero te sirva.